# How to remove hydrate from Fe(NO3)3 . 9H2O?

Tags: electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry, teaching-lab

I am currently in a dilemma where I need to have pure Iron (III) nitrate, but I have Iron (III) nitrate 9 hydrate in order to do a lab experiment where I investigate voltaic cell. I am pretty sure the hydrate will mess up the results, so I want to remove the hydrate to give $\ce{Fe(NO3)3}$. Is there any way for me to do this?

Comment: What kind of voltaic cell would require an _anhydrous_ salt? I thought they are mostly about water solutions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your voltaic cell going to be a *wet* cell? If so, account for the water. Even many "dry" cells have an electrolyte paste.

Comment: @BenNorris It is! What do you mean by accounting the water? Should I take note of the change in water levels?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to heat the sample.[Water of Crystallization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_of_crystallization)

For the ferric nitrate I recommend adjusting the temperate at 110$^\circ$C [see wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_nitrate)

Comment: I can't find anything on that Wikipedia page indicating that you could obtain the anhydrous material by heating to 110C. I did see that the nonahydrate _boils_ at 125C.

Comment: True, boiling of nonahydrate means that it is losing water, but it is never stated that it loses _all_ water, or that it doesn't hydrolyze in the process. More importantly, when the OP is going to shoot himself in the leg, it is a good practice **not** to help them with that, even if that's what the question literally asks for.

Comment: In the Water of Crystallization page it states that it loses water.
I suggest that you do a [TGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermogravimetric_analysis) or [DSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_scanning_calorimetry) beforehand. This will identify how much of the water is lost during heating and at what temperature